# jxl DateCell DateFormat

Tags: java, jxl

I am reading xls sheet ( made by business ) using jxl API.

Lets say we have **10/11/2014** from a column having Date.
When reading using code

```
if(row[i].getType()==CellType.DATE) {
            DateCell dc = (DateCell) row[i];
            return dc.getDate();
        }
```

**How does the API decide if it is 10 Nov or 11 Oct ?**

As of now when i try to read values like 10/41/2014 i get NULL ... and when i try to read **10/11/2014** I get 11 Oct 2014.
http://jexcelapi.sourceforge.net/resources/javadocs/2_6_10/docs/jxl/DateCell.html

Not sure if it is http://jexcelapi.sourceforge.net/resources/javadocs/2_6_10/docs/jxl/write/DateFormats.html#DEFAULT ... and how do i change it ? lets say two columns have diff date formats